# perl finda text in a file and then a new line addition

Tags: perl

Basically my requirement is a replace in a file using perl. The string that to be found is ' = '. The contents of the file should be modified in a way that end of the line where this string is found, it should add one more line as below. Please hep me here. I am not able to find on adding a new line also on how to get the word just before " = ". This has to be replaced in all occurences of the string within the file.

```
var b = "text"
var c = "integ"
```

should be replaced by

```
var b = "text"
println "the variable b is $b"
var c = "integ"
println "the variable c is $c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following one liner

```
perl -ne 'next unless (/=/); s/(var\s*(\w+)\s*\=.+)/$1\nprintln "the variable $2 is \$$2"/; print; ' input.txt
```

Then read the following links you will get a idea about what I did.

[next](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html)

[unless](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unless.html)

[Regular Expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)  `\w`  , `\s` , `.` , `+` ,`*`

[Substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) `s///`

[RegEx grouping](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching) `()` , `$1` , `$2`

Comment: I will try this and thanks a lot for the links for giving the hints and explanation. '/=/' - will this check the end of the file?

Comment: @Suresh Means.? please share the some sample

Comment: In your code after unless we have unless (/=/). Does that check for end of file?

Comment: @Suresh For check the end of file use [END](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/END.html). `perl -ne 'END{print; } ' input.txt` it will print the end of line.